# Probability of the rate of change of a filtered random process

Tags: frequency-spectrum, impulse-response, gaussian, random-process, probability

I am given the following problem: I have a filter with impulse response $h(t) = e^{-10t}, t \leq 0$, and autocorrelation function of the input signal, which is WDS and Gaussian with median equal to 0, of: $R_X(\tau) = \frac{\sin 20 \tau}{\tau}$. Amongst other things, I am asked to find the probability that the rate of change of the output is greater than 1V/s, but I am getting confused as of what to do here. I thought of using a relation like: $\frac{dY(t)}{dt} = X(t)$ and compute the impulse response using this, but I get lost. Am I losing something? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**: I tried using the above fact and I end up with $|H'(w)|^2 = \frac{1}{\omega^2}$, and thus I find that the power is the following integral of: $\sigma^2 = P = \int S_{y'} = \int |H'(\omega)|^2 S_y(f)  = \int \frac{1}{\omega^2} S_y(f)df$, and I have found the $S_y = \frac{\pi}{2\pi} (\Pi(\omega + 20) - \Pi(\omega - 20))$. Is something like this correct?

Comment: sure it's $t\le0$? That makes the impulse response explode!

Comment: Positive! It's not a mistake, the problem stated $t \leq 0$.

Comment: What is WDS? ${}{}$

Comment: Hm, your system produces infinite output for any nonzero input at some time $t$. Far as I can tell, the derivative of this is also unbounded and hence your probability is = 1